# Programmatically fetching definition of a word

Tags: php, javascript, api, rest

I am writing a social app where people will use TAGs for organizing their articles. These tags are shared across the site and each tag needs to have some description with it.

I wonder if there is any way I can programmatically fetch it from a resource like wikipedia. (say the first paragraph).

The tags will be typically associated with brands products and services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP");
preg_match("/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/", $contents, $match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/45c56.php

EDIT: Looks like they don't like non-validated browser agents. You'll have to do it with curl
EDIT2: curl with browser agent:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP");
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match("/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/", $contents, $match);
$match[1] = preg_replace("|\[[0-9]\]|", "", strip_tags($match[1]));
echo (($match[1]));
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ad578.php

Comment: Somewhat servers the purpose but I would have loved something that returns the plain definition in JSON format.

Comment: @Akshar: What are you reffering to?

Comment: I think you need to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true as well for arbitrary definitions because http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/php will redirect to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/indian railways to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Railways and so on.

Comment: If you want to scrape content from Wikipedia, use their API (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) or the raw output (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP?action=raw). Both are lighter on Wikimedia's servers, and easier for you to parse.